# Change AppWeb display language

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, language

Is it possible to change language of AppWeb (to different one than on SiteCollection)? I do not mean localization, but changing display language of default elements(i.e. ribbon). On my main site collection I am able to change this without any problems, but cannot find a way to do same with appweb.

Thanks in advance